# icon at left with spacing but border according to text

Tags: html, css

If I use like this :

```
a{
background: url('path') no-repeat left center;
padding-left: 50px;
border-bottom: 2px dashed;
}
```

this will produce like ths:

[image]

but if I use `margin-left: 50px;` this will produce like this:

[image]

How can I make like this:

[image]

Comment: use `:before`, and remove border bottom for this

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML have to be like this

```
<a href="#"><span>some text</span></a>
```

so you can style your link and your text separately

```
a{
  background: url('path') no-repeat left center;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
a span {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:before`, and remove border bottom. Something like this:

```
a {
  padding-left: 40px;
  display: inline-block; 
  position: relative; 
  border-bottom: 2px dashed;
}

  a::before {
    content: "";
    width: 40px; height: 100%;
    background: url('path') no-repeat left center;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: -40px;
  }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mn2Wg/

Comment: this will be a link so yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a {
    border-bottom: 2px dashed;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: url('path') no-repeat left center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: -45px;
}
```

Also, check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/2Xmuc/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GCpQa/

```
a {
    border-bottom: 2px dashed;
    margin-left: 40px; /* play with this margin as you want */
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    width: 30px; /* image width */
    height: 30px; /* image height */
    background: #ff0000; /* put you image background here */
    left: -40px; /* play with this position as you want */
}
```